# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [x: number] }'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can someone help me solve this problem? Basically, I get an error saying `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [x: number] }'`

I am not sure how else would I describe my interface, but here's how it looks.

```
export interface Payload {
    filter: Array<FilterArray>,
}

interface FilterArray {
    [id: number]: Filter
}
interface Filter {
    operator: string,
    id: number,
    type: string,
}
```

And when I try something like:

```
payloadFilter.filter.splice(payloadFilter.filter.indexOf(filterId), 1)
```

I get the error that I described above. Any thoughts or someone who can help solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Did you mean to use `Filter` instead of `PayloadFilterArray`?

Answer (score 0):

I can explain the error.  It's harder to explain how to fix it because I don't know what you are trying to do.

I have a feeling that you aren't fully understanding your data types here.  Assuming that `payloadFilter` is of type `Payload`, that would be something like this:

```
const someFilter: Filter = {/**...*/}

const payloadFilter: Payload = {
  filter: [
    {
      0: someFilter,
    },
    {
      7: someFilter,
      99: someFilter,
    }
  ]
}
```

Your typings say that the property `filter` of `Payload` is an `array` of `object`s with numeric keys and `Filter` values.  Is that really what it looks like?

The function `Array.prototype.indexOf` looks for the index of a specific value in an array, so the argument must match the type of that array's elements.  Here, the type of `payloadFilter.filter` is `Array<FilterElement>` and its elements have the type `FilterElement`, so you can only call `indexOf` with a `FilterElement`.  Instead you are calling it with a `number` and you get the error that you've posted here.